# How do I do localization with Appcelerator?

Tags: internationalization, appcelerator-mobile

I want to use strings so I don't have to have if statements for every language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every project, there is a directory called "i18n". In the subdirectory for "en", there is a  file called "strings.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="name">Hello</string>
</resources>
```

In your code, you can reference it like so:

```
L('name');
```

You can read more about the global L function [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Global-method-L).

Answer (score 1):

Always try searching 'wiki titanium {keywords}' when looking for Titanium help as the Appcelerator Wiki has tons of good stuff, but bad SEO. Here is the guide https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Internationalizing+your+Application/

Answer (score 0):

Latest answer is from 2012, so [this is the current location of the documentation](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/internationalization.html).
If it is moved, search for "Axway SDK How-tos Internationalization"